# What condition must be exist for this statement about real analysis to be true?

Tags: real-analysis

What condition must be exist for this statement about real analysis to be true? Or is it always true? please prove it.

$\max(f(x), g(x)) = \frac{f(x)+g(x)+|f(x)-g(x)|}{2}$

Hints is okay for this problem, because i have no idea how to start this proof.

please prove your answer since i am not in college.

Comment: I know you get this a lot, but:

What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BrettFrankel - Temperory cannot even start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try proving this more general statement : 
   $$
   \max(a,b) = \frac{a+b + |a-b|}2
   $$
   by treating separately the cases $a > b$ and $a \le b$.
2. Deduce your question from 1.

Hope that helps,